# removeFromSuperview() suddenly no longer working

Tags: ios, swift

I have a `UIView` subclass loaded from a xib like so:

```
// The xib custom view
private var view: UIView!

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    xibSetup()
}

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    xibSetup()
}

/**
* Setting up the view
*/
private func xibSetup() {
    view = loadViewFromNib()

    // use bounds not frame or it'll be offset
    view.frame = bounds

    // Make the view stretch with containing view
    view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight

    // Adding custom subview on top of our view (over any custom drawing > see note below)
    addSubview(view)

}

/**
* Loading the custom view from a nib
*/
private func loadViewFromNib() -> UIView {
    // Load the nib
    let bundle = NSBundle(forClass: self.dynamicType)
    let nib = UINib(nibName: "EditImageView", bundle: bundle)

    // Assumes UIView is top level and only object in PapControls.xib file
    let view = nib.instantiateWithOwner(self, options: nil)[0] as! UIView
    return view
}

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    blurView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: .Dark))
    blurView.frame = self.bounds
    blurView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "tappedOnBlur:"))
}
```

Inside this view, I have a view called `blurView` that I'm adding behind a `UITextView`. It's added to the view like so:

```
self.view.insertSubview(blurView, belowSubview:textOverlay)
```

When I use the `UITapGestureRecognizer` on the `blurView`, the `blurView` should be removed using this code:

```
func tappedOnBlur(tapGesture: UITapGestureRecognizer?) {
    blurView.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

Originally, I was adding this subclass as a subview to a view and it worked perfectly. However, I am now using a `UIViewController` with its `view` set to the subclass so I can push it into view using a `UINavigationController`. Now that I've done this, if I try to call `tappedOnBlur:`, it doesn't remove it from the view. Strangely, if I use `blurView.isDescendantOfView(self.view)` it returns false (both before I try to remove it and after).

Does anyone know what's going on here?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found out it's the way blurView is being loaded. I have moved the code in `layoutSubviews()` setting up blurView and it's working fine. I thought I could use `layoutSubviews()` like `viewDidLoad()` in a `UIViewController` but obviously not